# How to separate a dataframe in order to plot separate histograms?

Tags: r, dataframe, histogram

I have a df that looks like the following:

[image: screenshot]

How would I go about plotting a histogram of `IndividualRate` for each state on one graph? I could use `subset()` but as there are 40+ states there has to be a more efficient way.

Comment: did any of the answers below help you to solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

I always forget `by`, but it's much better here, no additional library, shorter, no workaround and you get the output as well:

```
by(df1$data,df1$state,hist)
```

**Old answer**

you don't need to create separate data.frames, you can use `dplyr` and `group_by`

```
library(dplyr)
df1%>% group_by(state) %>% do({hist(.$data);tibble()})
```

`do` must return a `data.frame` (or `tibble`), that's why I ended the expression with `tibble()`

**data**

```
df1 <- data.frame(state = rep(c("a","b","c"),100),data=sample(1000,300))
head(df1)
#   state data
# 1     a  401
# 2     b  599
# 3     c   36
# 4     a  649
# 5     b  116
# 6     c  905
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by [Moody](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46091274/3817004), there is no reason to split up a data.frame if the task can be solved using grouping. The `data.table` package allows to execute arbitrary code.

```
# create sample data
set.seed(1L)
df1 <- data.frame(state = rep(LETTERS[1:3], 100), value = sample(1000, 300))

# create one histogram for each state
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, hist(value), by = state]
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like

**example data**

```
df <- data.frame(state = rep(c("AK","AL","AR"),each=100), data=runif(300)*1000)
```

**multiple histograms on single plot**

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=data, fill=state, label=state)) +
  geom_histogram(stat="bin") +
  facet_wrap(~state, nrow=length(unique(df$state)))
```